# How to get the amount data from JSON (from SQL DB), and insert that within an already existing WHILE loop?

Tags: php, sql, json, while-loop, foreach

I'm making an *order* page where people can see their past orders.

Currently, I'm getting the data like this:

```
$qry = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `id` = ? AND `user_id` = ?";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($qry);
$stmt->bind_param("ii", $order, $id);
$stmt->execute();
$order = $stmt->get_result()->fetch_object();

$data = utf8_encode($order->products);
$dataAssoc = json_decode($data, true);`
```

This is then read out in the HTML (for each product in the `products` column) like this;

(Reads out product title, version, price, etc.)

```
if (!$dataAssoc == "") {
              foreach ($dataAssoc as $key => $value) {
                
                // Get product data
                $qry = "SELECT * FROM `products` WHERE `id`= ?";
                $stmt = $conn->prepare($qry);
                $stmt->bind_param("i", $value);
                $stmt->execute();
                $productData = $stmt->get_result();
                
                while ($product = $productData->fetch_object()) {
                  echo "
                    <div class='col'>
                      <div class='product'>
                        <div class='thumbnail'>
                            <img src='assets/images/product/product-thumb/". $product->thumbnail . "' alt='product image'>
                        </div>
                        <div class='product-content'>
                          <div class='inner'>
                            <h5 class='title'>". $product->name . " (" . $product->version .")</h5>
                            <div class='product-price'>
                              <span class='price current-price'>€". str_replace('.', ',', $product->price) . "</span>
                            </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  ";
                }
              }
            }
```

---

## Now, as for what I'm trying to accomplish;

I've also got an `amounts` column that saves the ordered product amounts (originally from `cart` table) as JSON;
i.e: `{ "1":"3", "2":"2", "3":"7" }` (with the second number being the amount).

Similar to how the products are saved in JSON;
i.e: `{ "1":"9", "2":"12", "3":"2" }` (with the second number being the product ID).

---

What would be the best approach to get these amount values into the original WHILE loop? I've tried getting the amounts data seperately;

```
$amounts     = utf8_encode($order->amounts);
$amountAssoc = json_decode($amounts, true);
```

and putting that within the original WHILE through;

```
if (!$amountAssoc == "") {
     foreach ($amountAssoc as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
   }
}
```

This resulted in all product amounts being written out after one another, every time a new product was loaded in.

---

What would be the best way for me to implement this?
Should I stick with this WHILE loop and restructure it, should I restructure the database or is there some simple solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've figured out a (pretty simple) solution to this myself, and I'll post it here just in case anybody else comes across a similar issue and is looking for an answer.

I've removed the `amounts` column and changed the `products` column to include that data.

Where it was first;

```
{ "1":"3", "2":"2", "3":"7" }
```

(with the first number being simply a counter going up for each product,

It is now like;

```
{ "5":"3", "7":"2", "2":"7" }
```

With the first (key) being the product, and the second (value) being its amount.

---

**With it being in a *single* JSON column, reading its value out became as simple as echoing `$value`.**